# Failed to start emulator: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, android-emulator, android-sdk

I downloaded the Android SDK bundle for Linux because I want to start making some apps, but I've run into a couple of problems here. When I tried to create an emulator through the AVD Manager, and I tried to run it, I got the following error message:

```
Starting emulator for AVD 'AVDTEST'
Failed to start emulator: Cannot run program "/home/luke/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk//tools/emulator": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

If you look, you will see that *there is an extra slash before the `tools` directory*, so I'm asking if anyone knows where I can go to change that path.

I tried running the emulator explicitly from the command line, but, even though I can clearly see that the file is there, and I am now providing the correct path, I still get the no such file/dir error.

Answer (score 0):

Change the SDK directory path from Eclipse settings to the root of your SDK path. Also, `chmod` the files to executables.

Comment: 1. I can not find a settings option in eclipse, that's why I asked this question.

Comment: 2. In the SDK manager, the ADK path is already displayed as: /home/luke/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140702/sdk

Comment: Window -> Preferences -> Android and browse to the SDK folder. Update sdk and the Eclipse ide if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, but like I said, the Path to sdk is correct, its that extra slash that is messing things up, I'm wondering where I can go to change that specific path (i'm checking for updates now, although everything should be the latest version, because i just downloaded them both today)

Comment: yeah no updates to perform

Comment: Go to your sdk path and try starting avd manually

Comment: You're talking about via the command line right? I tried that earlier, check the edit on my post